# Method for finding all the solutions of the $n$ queens problem for a given $n$?

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, chessboard

Is there an easy way of obtaining all the solutions of the $n$ queens problem for a given $n$? An algorithm online? Paper, or something?

I only found a code written in c, but I'm not a c programmer, if I could find a more general algorithm so I could implement it myself, it'd be far better

Or maybe a theorem of an alternative way of computing which could be easily implementable?
any ideas?

Algorithm complexity is irrelevant since I'm only going to use it for small examples

Comment: I don't get it?

It redirects to another question I made a while ago in this site?